# json-server - Using nested request

Tags: json, json-server

I just start using [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) and struggling with one thing. I want to have URL which are nested so e.g. to get user orgs, request would looks like:
`/rest/user/orgs` and will return array of user orgs

```
{
    "rest": {
        "user": {
            "select": {
                "org": []
            },
            "orgs": [{
                "id": "5601e1c0-317c-4af8-9731-a1863f677e85",
                "name": "DummyOrg"
            }],
            "logout": {}
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: i also wanted to know how to do that.

Comment: Hi @Tamesh try to check this:
https://github.com/typicode/json-server/issues/514

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported by the library. The way to get this working is to add a custom routes file to de server, where you will map (or redirect) requests made to `/rest/user/` to `/`.

`db.json`

```
 {
            "select": {
                "org": []
            },
            "orgs": [{
                "id": "5601e1c0-317c-4af8-9731-a1863f677e85",
                "name": "DummyOrg"
            }],
            "logout": {}
    }
```

`routes.json`

```
{
  "/rest/user/*": "/$1"
}
```

and then run it using `json-server db.json --routes routes.json`

Comment: that means the db.json structure has to change right.

Comment: Yes, it will trim down to : {
            "select": {
                "org": []
            },
            "orgs": [{
                "id": "5601e1c0-317c-4af8-9731-a1863f677e85",
                "name": "DummyOrg"
            }],
            "logout": {}
        }